# Why does a coconut have exactly three "holes"?

Tags: evolution, botany, development, fruit, flowers

Why do coconuts have exactly three "holes", as seen in this picture?

[image]

A theory says:
As coconut is a sibling of palm, somehow long time ago, three palms were in a same husk. Based on evolution theory, it's how the coconut was born in the world with three holes.

Reference:

"*Why does a coconut have exactly three eyes?*", [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-coconut-have-exactly-three-eyes/answers/15116975)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. Are you wanting someone to clarify or confirm this theory?

Comment: That's not evolutionary theory, that's mythology.

Comment: Is this a question?  If so, it desperately needs an edit.

Comment: Based on strictly on evolutionary theory: "because it can".

Comment: This was necessary to invent bowling.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The three "holes" are the result of the 3 [carpels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gynoecium#Carpels) in coconut flowers, and three carpels is typical of the family [Arecaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecaceae) (Palms). The "holes" are actually germination pores, where one is usually functional and the other two are plugged. The new coconunt shoot will emerge from the functional, open, germination pore.

For further info and pictures, see [this webpage](http://waynesword.palomar.edu/ecoph10.htm) or the paper [*Morphological and anatomical studies of the coconut*](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://edepot.wur.nl/288905&ved=2ahUKEwjhtabQvJLaAhWjE5oKHa1nDCIQFjACegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw2n-iXvGR_sbOtuSCUJMzzq) (Smit 1970, link to pdf), which holds a wealth of information.

Comment: This must be truly *the* answer with the highest vote-to-text ratio ever! +1